# SQL Join with nested table returns wrong data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, mariadb

The following behavior confused me even though I consider myself experienced with database operations.

I have 2 tables, one for countries and one for covid cases per country per date. Basically they look like this:

`countries`:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Argentina |
| 2 | Brazil |
| 3 | Cuba |
| 4 | Ecuador |

`cases`:

| id | country_id | active_cases | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 2019 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 | 2020 |
| 3 | 1 | 30 | 2021 |
| 4 | 2 | 100 | 2019 |
| 5 | 2 | 200 | 2020 |
| 6 | 2 | 300 | 2021 |
| 7 | 3 | 1000 | 2019 |
| 8 | 3 | 2000 | 2020 |
| 9 | 3 | 3000 | 2021 |
| 10 | 4 | 10000 | 2019 |
| 11 | 4 | 20000 | 2020 |
| 12 | 4 | 30000 | 2021 |

^ This is just simplification of the real problem. I want to join the 2 tables in a way that I get latest active cases for each country. With the following query I can easily extract the data from the `cases` table grouped by `country_id` descending.

```
SELECT *
FROM cases
GROUP BY country_id DESC
```

It will return table like:

| id | country_id | active_cases | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 4 | 30000 | 2021 |
| 9 | 3 | 3000 | 2021 |
| 6 | 2 | 300 | 2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 30 | 2021 |

Now, I would like to just add the country name to this result table. If I just join this table with the countries table to get the country name instead its id, it returns completely different numbers (like they are ordered by date ascending)

```
SELECT * 
FROM countries
JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM cases
  GROUP BY country_id DESC
) AS cases 
  ON countries.id = cases.country_id
```

This returns data like:

| id | name | id | country_id | active_cases | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Argentina | 1 | 1 | 10 | 2019 |
| 29 | Brazil | 4 | 2 | 100 | 2019 |
| 36 | Cuba | 7 | 3 | 1000 | 2019 |
| 4 | Ecuador | 10 | 3 | 10000 | 2019 |

Any ideas why is this happening and how would I go to get a table where all cases from 2021 are shown for each country?

**EDIT:** Here are copy-paste queries to replicate the database:

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(16)
);

CREATE TABLE `cases` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `country_id` int(10) UNSIGNED,
  `active_cases` int(11),
  `date` int(11)
);

INSERT INTO `countries` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Argentina'),
(2, 'Brazil'),
(3, 'Cuba'),
(4, 'Ecuador');

INSERT INTO `cases` (`country_id`, `active_cases`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 10, 2019),
(1, 20, 2020),
(1, 30, 2021),
(2, 100, 2019),
(2, 200, 2020),
(2, 300, 2021),
(3, 1000, 2019),
(3, 2000, 2020),
(3, 3000, 2021),
(4, 10000, 2019),
(4, 20000, 2020),
(4, 30000, 2021);
```

Comment: Tables have no order, result sets can be ordered. An order by without top/limit in a subquery has no effect. PS This is a faq. But to google properly you have to actually phrase (in many clear concise complete ways) what your problem is. PS A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code.

Comment: Which version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: Server version: 10.3.25-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please format initialization code as a table. And then the grid versions are redundant & possibly different & so don't belong. PS Also your overall goal is a faq. There's even a tag, greatest n per group.

Comment: "`SELECT * FROM cases GROUP BY country_id DESC`" -- This query is malformed and most proper SQL engines would reject it. Not all the columns selected are either in the `GROUP BY` clause or an argument to an aggregation function. Sadly old or badly configured MySQL instances allow such queries anyway. But the results can be surprising and even vary each time the query is executed. This is what you experience here.

Comment: @stickybit Standard SQL does not always disallow selecting non-aggreggated non-grouped columns. A DBMS can allow columns that are single-valued per (aka functionally dependent on) the set of grouping columns. MySQL 8.0 supports this functionality package (E051-04) & PostgreSQL partially does.

Comment: @philipxy: Yes, you're right, I missed to add that detail, thanks for adding it. But in this case `country_id` is no key of `cases` so that doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running MariaDB 10.2 or later, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a CTE to get the latest cases data for each `country_id`, this can then be joined to `countries` to get the country name:

```sql
WITH latest AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
  FROM cases
)
SELECT c.name, l.active_cases, l.date
FROM latest l
JOIN countries c ON c.id = l.country_id
WHERE l.rn = 1
```

Output:

```
name        active_cases    date
Argentina   30              2021
Brazil      300             2021
Cuba        3000            2021
Ecuador     30000           2021
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d6ad5f2b46fcec71d3ced8437131281b)

Answer (score 1):

Your inner query is grouping by `country_id` and sorting that DESC. The fact that it is giving you all the results from `2021` per your example is coincidental based on the data in your table. This is why your joined query returns the unexpected data.

If you're looking for the latest cases then you should add an explicit `ORDER BY` to your inner query, something like the following:

```
SELECT countries.*, active_cases, date
FROM countries
JOIN (
  SELECT cases.country_id, active_cases, date
  FROM cases
  JOIN (
    SELECT country_id, MAX(date) as target_date
    FROM cases
    GROUP BY country_id 
  ) as latest
    ON cases.country_id = latest.country_id
      AND cases.date = latest.target_date
) as latest_cases
  ON countries.id = latest_cases.country_id;
```

Edit: Replacing with a query using nested subqueries, but the above answer works with row partitions which is cleaner.

Comment: Nope, still returns the oldest. Instead joining each country with cases from 2021, it joins each country with data from 2019 even after ordering by date DESC.

Comment: The suggested query doesn't order right even if using the nested query only i.e. 
(SELECT * FROM cases GROUP BY country_id ORDER BY date DESC) returns data from 2019 instead 2021

Comment: You're right. I've updated the query to one that works + fixed the syntax issues that I got confused with.